# How to get the result of a task when using Task.WhenAny to account for a timeout

Tags: c#, xamarin

I need to add a timeout feature to the task calls in a mobile app. I attempted to complete this by using Task.WhenAny as shown below. This returns the task that finishes first. My problem is that originally I was getting the return value from this task, and I still need it if the task does not get timed out.

```
Task task = restService.GetRequestAsync(articleAdr, articleParams);
var response = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token));
```

response is simply the task that was completed first. How do I get it's result?

Answer (score 3):

I can think of three different possibilities for this scenario.

The first two can be found in [Peter Bons' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41925307/2607840).

The third is storing off your two tasks then checking the status after the `await Task.WhenAny()` is completed.

```
var workerTask = restService.GetRequestAsync(articleAdr, articleParams);
var cancellationTask = Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token);

await Task.WhenAny(workerTask, cancellationTask);
if (workerTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
{
  // Note that this is NOT a blocking call because the Task ran to completion.
  var response = workerTask.Result;

  // Do whatever work with the completed result.
}
else
{
  // Handle the cancellation.
  // NOTE: You do NOT want to call workerTask.Result here. It will be a blocking call and will block until 
  // your previous method completes, especially since you aren't passing the CancellationToken.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One question though, how is your `CancellationTokenSource` created and initialized and when do you call `Cancel` on it?

Best would be if your method `GetRequestAsync` would accept a `CancellationToken`. Always prefer that if possible since you can create a `CancellationTokenSource` that initiates a cancel after a set period. Would save you the call to `Task.WhenAny`.

In general, there are multiple options, one is outlined below:

```
// Set timeout of 1 second
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 

...

Task task = restService.GetRequestAsync(articleAdr, articleParams);

// Wait until timeout or request is done.
await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1), cts.Token));

// If the cancellation is not yet requested the request was done before the timeout was reached
if(!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var response = await task;  
}
```

Another options is this:

```
Task requestTask = restService.GetRequestAsync(articleAdr, articleParams);
var firstCompletedTask = await Task.WhenAny(requestTask, Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token));
if(firstCompletedTask == requestTask)
{
    cts.Cancel(); // optionally, will cancel the delay task since it is of no use any more.
    var response = await requestTask;
}
```

A completed task can be awaited as many times as you want and it will always yield the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take a look to @jamesmontemagno MVVM Helpers. There is an extesion that helps you to add a timeout to a task

[MVVM Helpers - Utils](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers#utils)

Here you can find a video where James explain how to use it

[The-Xamarin-Show-12-MVVM-Helpers](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/The-Xamarin-Show-12-MVVM-Helpers)

(near 26:38 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

> I need to add a timeout feature to the task calls in a mobile app. I attempted to complete this by using Task.WhenAny as shown below.

First, you should be aware that by not passing the `CancellationToken` to `GetRequestAsync`, you're not actually cancelling the request. It will continue processing.

Second, I find your code rather odd, since there are *two* timeouts possible in its current state: the `Task.Delay` may complete, or the `CancellationToken` may be signaled. One of these (`Task.Delay`) is a normal task completion, and the other (`CancellationToken`) is a true cancellation.

If the `CancellationToken` *is* your timeout, then you can use the `WaitAsync` method from my `Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks` library:

```
Task task = restService.GetRequestAsync(articleAdr, articleParams);
await task.WaitAsync(cts.Token);
var result = await task;
```

If the `CancellationToken` is a user-requested cancellation, and that the `Task.Delay` is the timeout you want to apply, then I'd recommend modeling your timeout as another kind of cancellation:

```
Task task = restService.GetRequestAsync(articleAdr, articleParams);
using (var timeoutCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cts.Token))
{
  timeoutCts.CancelAfter(1000);
  await task.WaitAsync(timeoutCts.Token);
}
var result = await task;
```

If you don't wish to use `Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks`, then your best option is probably something like this (assuming `Task.Delay` is intended as a timeout and `CancellationToken` is a user cancellation request):

```
Task task = restService.GetRequestAsync(articleAdr, articleParams);
var completed = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token));
if (completed != task)
  throw new OperationCanceledException();
var result = await task;
```